How should I manage dependencies between multiple microservices (with maven)?
I'm trying to build a SpringBoot microservice-architecture for example a ShopSystem which has a dependency to a other microservice like "Customer". As the dependency-managementtool I'm using Maven and the customer creates a JPA-Repository, but now when I try to put the customer-dependency into the shopsystem pom.xml, the shopsystem tries to create another customer repository. So the shop-service won't start because there already exists a customer-repository.
I want the customer-dependency in the shopsystem because I'm using the "Customer.class" in the shop as a return type of the CustomerService-Methods, for example to retrieve customerId's, the cart of the customer and so on.
How should I handle the dependencies between those services or should I only return the customerId, which would be an Integer because of information-hiding, separation-of-concern...
The services are connected via rest with OpenFeign if it's good to know for the problem and they are running in separate SpringBoot-Application processes.
I've seen something with a parent.pom, but I'm not sure if that would solve my problem and for me that doesn't seem to be like a clean solution.
I've tried to exclude the "database"-package in the customer.jar, because I only want one specific class out of the service and nothing else, but that didn't worked like I imagined. If this would have worked, is it a proper thing to do or should this be avoided in practice, because out of my view it would be the easiest solution for my problem?

In microservices architecture, internal service logic or database models should not be exposed to other microservices.
Define REST API contracts in the Customer service that exposes necessary operations such as retrieving customer details. Create DTO classes such as CustomerDTO in both the Customer and ShopSystem services and use OpenFeign client in the ShopSystem service to consume the API. The DTO objects include only the necessary fields that the ShopSystem needs, such as customerId etc.
The ShopSystem does not directly depend on the Customer service's database or internal implementation.

Okay, so now I would create a customerDTO in ShopSystem and just copy&paste into a customerDTO in CustomerService and delete the dependency in the pom.xml of ShopSystem. But what happens if the customerDTO in ShopSystem needs to be changed, so i got to remember to change the customerDTO in CustomerService as well, this seems to  disregard the DRY-Principal. But between microservices there shouldn't be direct dependencies (like through maven), am I understanding that right?

Ideally, each service maintains its DTO class to avoid tight coupling. However, for complex data structures that need to be shared across multiple services might be preferable to introduce a common jar containing the DTOs.

That means there would be another project/module containing the DTOs but no business-logic to share just those DTOs? That "project" is then in the dependencies of for example customer and shopsystem, right?

@atze119 that's a great way to introduce tight coupling which was the opposite of what gkatiforis started saying, but then veered into a tight coupling suggestion :). In microservice architecture service A is just returning JSON as far as anyone else is concerned. Service B is responsible for doing whatever it wants with it. If B wants to deserialize to a POJO, then it defines its own POJO. What if a Python, etc. app needs to call your service? How it is going to use your POJO lib?

@atze119 if you're worried about breaking changes, you either 1) never remove or rename a property 2) version your API

@SledgeHammer Oh okay, I think I understand now. So my Customer returns some JSON (thats 100% clear) and in ShopService it can be deserialized in what ever the shop wants it to be, as long as it fits to the datatypes?

@atze119 Yeah, in a large scale environment, you may be talking about 100s or 1000s of services. You don't want to have to update 1000 services to the new version of your POJO lib and then redeploy all of them. Adding a property is not a breaking change (UNLESS there are schemas involved), only deleting or renaming is. Letting each service own its own DTO (which is what gkatiforis originally said) let's you do stuff like prune them down if you don't want some fields or "attach your own properties" for internal use ... but if pruning is your thing, that's more GraphQL ...

Okay, yeah that makes more sense now. Thank you for clearing that up! :)
